# How to read this json string using c#?

Tags: c#, json

```
"{\n  \"connections\": {\n    \"_total\": 1,\n    \"values\": [{\n \"apiStandardProfileRequest\": {\n        \"headers\": {\n \"_total\": 1,\n          \"values\": [{\n
```

I am unable to read attributes of this string format. Please suggest me how to read attributes from this string format.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676746/parse-json-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this method maybe useful

```
public static T Deserialise<T>(string json)
{
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms); // 
        return obj;
    } 
}
```

Also, just for reference, here is the Serialize method :

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static dynamic Deserialize(string content)
{
return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(content);
}

var f = Deserialize(json);
List<Name> list = new List<Name>();

foreach(var item1 in (Dictionary<string, object>) f)
{
Dictionary<string, object> item2 = (Dictionary<string, object>) item1.Value;

list.Add( new Name(){
    id = (int) item2["id"],
    name = (string) item2["name"],
    age = (int) item2["age"]
});             

}
```

This code also working fine ...