# how to read the variables inside a JSON string

Tags: c#, json

i have json string as following

```
string json = "{\"ID\":\"hid\",\"Specification\":\"hname\"}";
```

but i want to read Id and hname as following
string hid = hardwareidTextbox.Text;
            string hname = hardwarename_Textbox.Text;
how do i read variable vales in JSON string

Comment: See [Parse Json string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676746/parse-json-string-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```