# How to get(Parsing) Json Nested String (from API) data like object with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How to "get" JSON string?
Call API Server code:

```
import requests
file_name = os.path.join('','/home/pp2018/public/users/roger123/000000000285.jpg')
files = {'file': open(file_name, 'rb')}
url = "http://111.111.111.111:57149"
res = requests.post(url,files=files)
print(res.json())
```

Return value:

```
{"pic1": {"class_name": "dog1", "Pos": [11.11, 22.22, 33.33, 44.44], "Confidence": 0.98},
 "pic2": {"class_name": "dog2", "Pos": [99.99, 88.88, 77.77, 66.66], "Confidence": 0.99},
 "pic3": {"class_name": "dog3", "Pos": [33.33, 44.44, 55.55, 66.66], "Confidence": 0.97},
}
```

object command like

```
 GET --> print(***.pic2.Pos[0])            >>>  99.99
```

> my question is how to get 99.99

Comment: try simple assignment

Comment: `a["pic2"]["Pos"] = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]`?

Comment: That's not JSON, just plain Python dictionaries and lists. It's only JSON once you stringify it. But: what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What is the point of stringifying then immediately re-parsing the dictionary?! Given that you never use the string, why bother with the pretty formatting options? And where's the attempt to actually do what you describe?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your question, I have put all the codes into my question, and the data's is from API (Json formation).

Comment: Maybe you should include the API call in the code so we're not confused if you are only using a plain dictionary?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, I will do it now.

Comment: You've already answered your own question - use `json.loads`. Actually, with `requests`, you don't even need to do that because there's a method that applies the parsing for you: `res.json()`

Comment: Can you remove the definition of variable a and show how res is used?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is one way to deal with this issue, it will be used [addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict) package to handle this problem.

> addict is a Python module that gives you dictionaries whose values are
> both gettable and settable using attributes, in addition to standard
> item-syntax
>
> ...
>
> #### Installing
>
> You can install via pip
>
> ```
> pip install addict
> ```
>
> or through conda
>
> ```
> conda install addict -c conda-forge
> ```

Solution 1 :

```
import json
a ={"pic1": {"class_name": "dog1", "Pos": [11.11, 22.22, 33.33, 44.44], "Confidence": 0.98},
    "pic2": {"class_name": "dog2", "Pos": [99.99, 88.88, 77.77, 66.66], "Confidence": 0.99},
    "pic3": {"class_name": "dog3", "Pos": [33.33, 44.44, 55.55, 66.66], "Confidence": 0.97},
}
loaded_json = json.loads(json.dumps(a, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


from addict import Dict
mapping = Dict(loaded_json)

#print(mapping.pic1.Pos)  ## Get data
#mapping.pic1.Pos[0]="aa" ## Set data 
#print(mapping.pic1.Pos)
#print(mapping.pic2.Pos[0]) ## it will be show 99.99 

for i in mapping:
    #print (mapping[i]['Pos'])
    #print(mapping[i])
    for j in mapping[i]['Pos']:
        print(j)
```

reference [Parse Json string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676746/parse-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What? The functionality that isn't commented out doesn't require `addict` at all. If you were just asking *"how do I access a dictionary key as an attribute?"*, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4984647/3001761. And the `json.loads(json.dumps(...))` is just as pointless here as in the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks again, but my question is the data's from API(JSON data) so that I have tried to show what I got with JSon's data and I have to similar the same problem (JSON string) into my question content. sorry  Not "how do I access a dictionary key as an attribute?", it isn't I want.

Comment: Well given that that's the only thing `addict` gives you over the vanilla dictionary you already had, I really don't understand how this answers the question. Parsing the string makes sense if that's what you're receiving, but you could just start with the dictionary here - dumping and loading it again is a no-op.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks very much for your response, I will be modifying my question and answer, anyway, thank.

Comment: *"this package can transfer JSON data's to Dictionary"* - no, it can't. That's what `json.loads` is doing - `loaded_json` is *already* a dictionary. All wrapping it in `addict.Dict` does is let you access the keys as attributes, e.g. `mapping.pic1` instead of `mapping['pic1']` (which you don't do in any of the code you haven't commented out...).

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I have changed my content that is from the reference [GitHub](https://github.com/mewwts/addict). Hopefully, it can be more clear about the answer. thanks

Comment: You're still not actually using the features of that library at all, though, so using it **doesn't solve the problem**. I am certain I don't understand what your question actually is, but now I'm wondering if *you* do.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than dot notation, you use brackets

```
res.json()["pic2"]["Pos"][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `res.json()` returns a dict of dicts. So all you have to to is to store the result of `res.json()` in a variable (I assume you're going to need other values from it, and it will make inspection / debugging easier anyway) and [use the normal python dict/list access syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).